# Importing CSS into LESS

Tags: css, less

Is there an option in LESS to import the contents of a CSS file rather than adding an `@import` directive?

**Example**

```
//example.less
@import url("../Css/site.css");
@import url("components.less");

//example.css
@import url("site.css"); // I DON'T WANT THIS!
.component1 { ... }
.component2 { ... }
```

Can this be done with LESS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question; YES!

```
@import (less) url("../Css/site.css");
```

Comment: I would have chosen `inline`

Comment: you said you don' want to use @import directive and now you are using it?

Comment: @Leothelion I want to use it in the less file to import the css file, but I wan't the imported css to be added (inline) to the output/compiled css file, rather than just adding a css import directive. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please be more clear in your question..i think then you should do this @import (inline) '../Css/site.css';

Answer (score 8):

In less you have different options for importing.

> Syntax: @import (keyword) "filename";
>
> The following import directives have been implemented:
>
> - reference: use a Less file but do not output it
> - inline: include the source file in the output but do not process it
> - less: treat the file as a Less file, no matter what the file extension
> - css: treat the file as a CSS file, no matter what the file extension
> - once: only include the file once (this is default behavior)
> - multiple: include the file multiple times
> - optional: continue compiling when file is not found
>
> More than one keyword per @import is allowed, you will have to use
>   commas to seperate the keywords: Example: @import (optional,
>   reference) "foo.less";

more info in [docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options).

Comment: Ah! inline seems to compile faster too! +1 for completeness